# Syntax error in where clause in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

The error I am getting is **Syntax error in where clause** in Access.

Here is the code:

```
SQL = "Select * FROM tblPermitAgencyInformation  & WHERE [RecordID] = " & Me.AgencyInfoRecordID.Value
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
```

RecordID is an autonumber field and the AgencyInfoRecordID is an integer.

Comment: why the &?   If thats not right...tell us what the error is.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1099570/3820271)

Comment: Remove the first &.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you misread the article you state. It appears to be attempting to format the adhoc query in the text variable.
Note: it says

```
strSQL = "SELECT wazzle FROM bamsploot" & vbCrLf & " WHERE plumsnooker = 0"
```

You need to make sure that you have the ampersands outside of the quotes, (they are used to append variables and strings together in this case)

Follow June7 advice and remove the ampersand there. It should help you get running.

Make your code this:

```
SQL = "Select * FROM tblPermitAgencyInformation WHERE [RecordID] = " & Me.AgencyInfoRecordID.Value
```

Hope that helps

Comment: It absolutely does.  Thank you - I must have stared at it too long just dropped the & and it was fine.

Comment: Please mark as the answer if it is indeed what you feel the answer is.